# Tradingview alerts and just place trade through mt4

Tags: algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api, mt4

I can't really seem to find anything publicly available. I'm just looking for something that will be able to take my alerts coming in via email or webhook and just automatically place the trade for me on mt4. Pointing me in the right direction or if anyone has worked on a project like this before and has some code I would really appreciate it.

Comment: https://www.tradingview.com/chart/GBPUSD/uZqqdxEB-Auto-delivering-TradingView-Alerts-into-MT4-MT5/

Comment: Installation guide here: https://www.tradingview.com/chart/USDCAD/xMiBY0Qt-TradingView-Alerts-to-MT4-MT5-installation-guide/